# How to re-use Rcpp compiled dll

Tags: r, rcpp

Suppose I have compiled a code with two functions `f1` and `f2` using `Rcpp::sourceCpp('myPath/myCode.cpp')` and I located the `sourceCpp_123123.dll` that was created.

Now suppose I have two different batch files on Windows 7, both of which run `RScript -e "source('myRCode1.r')"` and `RScript -e "source('myRCode2.r')"` respectively. I want my two functions `f1` and `f2` to be available with each run of `RScript`.

I can certainly put in my code `myRCode1.r` and `myRCode2.r` to do `Rcpp::sourceCpp('myPath/myCode.cpp')` before rest of the code is run. Another alternative is to convert my two functions `f1` and `f2` into a package which is a little more involved process.

Is there any easy way to simply load the `sourceCpp_123123.dll` within `myRCode1.r` and `myRCode2.r` ?

I tried `dyn.load("myDllPath\sourceCpp_123123.dll")` with various permutations and combinations of `now=TRUE`, `local=TRUE`, `now=FALSE`, `local=FALSE`, but none of the options loaded the two functions.

However, when I tried `getLoadedDLLs`, I see that `sourceCpp_123123.dll` has been loaded!

Comment: Just created a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented earlier, this is where you want to use a package.

Or if you are one of those people opposed to packages on whichever grounds (none of which typically convince an experienced R user / programmer who will almost always advocate use of package), then you could cheat and just combine your two files into one.

Which would couple the two function sets. And you may already know that you can mix C++ and R code in one file as we do all the time over at the Rcpp Gallery...